# Programatically Remove TCP/IP restriction in XP/Vista/7

Tags: c#, testing, tcp

My company needs to internally test infrastructure.  Our organization is rapidly moving from a very small development environment to a larger more scalable production environment.  Specifically we want to flood some of our new request routers from the inside.  We need to write the tool ourselves, and it has to be automatable.  We can't use third-party tools because, to be frank, they're written by less than scrupulous hats and are virtually all are chock full of malware.

To be more specific, the tool is to be written in C# and the first obstacle we have to get past is overcoming kernel imposed restrictions on half-open outbound requests (we're clearly a Windows shop...I wouldn't be posting if we were all Linux).  We would be dealing with Vista.

Any tips on anything are greatly appreciated. Where to get started, open source tools (so they can be verified to not be malware), anything.  Thanks in advance.

And no, I'm not a hat or a script kiddie.

EDIT:  The main goal here is not the actual generation of the traffic (I can do that), but rather programmatically overcoming the OS imposed "10 half-open outbound requests" restriction.  Theoretically a single system should be able to spawn 255 of these half-open requests at a time, but the OS artificially locks this down.

Comment: What type of network traffic do you want to generate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to Vista SP2 (you say you're specifically dealing with Vista, although the title suggests differently) - the connection limit is removed in Vista SP2.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335036(WS.10).aspx?ppud=4

Notably, it's the last bullet point under Operating System Experience updates

And for added value...

How to turn it on again if you wanted...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969710

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to be the [winpcap driver](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/).  Note that many of these "kernel-imposed restrictions" are also imposed in hardware, in which case you are S.O.L. until you buy new hardware.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like very useful code.  I've combed through the documentation but it does not seem to include a way to overcome  the 10 half-open outbound connection restrictions.  Is this possible with winpcap?

Answer (score 1):

Is running mono on linux a possibility? You might need to write/use some third party unmanaged code I would imagine, but you would not have that restriction to deal with.

Comment: I wish I was using linux...then I could just abandon C# altogether and get this done in an afternoon with probably just bash.